Can I say "go by mass transit"?
To my mind, mass transit and public transport are synonymous. However, there are a lot more hits for go by public transport than for go by mass transit. For example:

Many people have seen the benefits of going to work by mass transit.

versus

Many people have seen the benefits of going to work by public transport.

Why is that so? How should the phrase "mass transit" be used?

They are not synonymous; a subway line with 24 trains an hour in each direction, each train carrying 1500 people, is 'mass transit'; a rural bus service of one journey per day that may carry 10 people is not; both are 'public transport'. You should check the meaning of 'mass' as a preceding adjective.

Sometimes oppressive regimes move large numbers of people (Nazi Germany / Jews, Myanmar / Rohingya,...) by "mass transit". But I wouldn't call that "public transport".

NGrams suggests "use mass transit" is more usual. "Go by mass transit" is understandable depending on context - we really need a sentence or context you want to use it in. As others mention, "mass transit" is not identical with "public transport" in meaning or use, and IMO someone without an interest in public policy, local government, urbanism, etc, would be far more likely to talk about "public transport".

Also, 'transit' is mainly American, and 'transport' is mainly British.

@MichaelHarvey Out of the options presented, I turn to "public transportation" most readily. Looks like it's been bit of a roller coaster: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=mass+transit%2Cpublic+transport%2Cpublic+transportation&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=3

(Also, I think you've got another answer-as-comment there.)

Again and again I say: many of these questions do not deserve a downvote. "How did get here today?" I came by mass transit.

Is the lack of context the reason why this question has been voted to be closed? If that's the case, I've just edited it.

Until today I had never heard of Mass Transit... See BrEng Ngram results and AmEng Ngram results

Originally, it's an urban planning term. In the UK, they have a study on MRT: Mass Rapid Transit. https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/1668871.pdf And in Bristol, UK, just mass transit : https://www.bristol.gov.uk/residents/streets-travel/transport-plans-and-projects/mass-transit-public-transport-plans

In your examples, either could be used. And mass transit aka public transport is on many UK sites, for those who doubt it, I have provided at least three examples. This question should not be downvoted, for pete's sake.

You've got at least 1 good answer below so I won't bother. But note well that 'mass transport' is an American English term, which is why British English speakers and speakers of other English dialects may not recognise it, and also that it is defined in the top US dictionary as "the transportation of large numbers of people by means of buses, subway trains, etc" so anyone saying it doesn't mean buses is wrong.

Until today I had never heard of Mass Transit... See BrEng Ngram, 1920 -2019, results

and AmEng Ngram, 1920-2019, results

From the American English chart it is clear that the phrase mass transit is in sharp decline whereas in British English the expression public transport has always been greatly preferred in various forms of publications and literature. In AmEng, the same expression has seen a steady increase since the 1980s (this could also be due to British authors whose books are published in the US); however, it has always been below that of public transportation.
In an interview conducted by Leonardo DiCaprio for ABC News’ “Planet Earth 2000”, the 25-year-old actor had the opportunity to talk to the then President of the United States, William J. Clinton, on the topic of climate change. The environmental special was taped on March 31, 2000, but only two minutes were actually broadcast by ABC on 22nd April. [Emphasis in bold are mine]

DiCaprio: Many people have said in the past that the American dream was to buy a car and live in the suburbs. But it has created massive problems that have made us more reliant on our cars. Since it is so difficult for us to convince people to use mass transportation, how can we promote hybrid vehicles and convince people to give up their SUV‘s? For instance, if it only costs $575 a car to make them cleaner, why can't you make it a law, like seat-belts?
The President: Well, I'm not sure it only costs $575 to make them cleaner in terms of greenhouse emissions. But let me say what I think ought to be done. I think–first of all, I think if these SUV‘s are going to be sustainable over the long run, they also are going to have to become much more fuel-efficient and be able to run on alternative fuels. And I think the American people would pay a little more if they would do that. And the auto companies for the first time have said now that they want to bring in the SUV‘s and their other less efficient vehicles into this sort of new energy future that we're trying to build.
Secondly, I think that people will take mass transit more if it works better. I've worked very hard to support more investments in mass transit to make it more convenient and faster, including more high-speed rail. And I still believe that as our urban areas become more and more congested, quite apart from pollution in the air, if we can have clean, efficient, and fast mass transit, people will begin to take it more and more and more because they can do other things; they're not wasting so much time if they're riding the train. […]

I think it is likely that the phrase “go by mass transit” was never that popular because mass transit encompasses different means of public transport such as railways and buses. Google News appears to confirm that the phrase "take mass transit" is the more popular choice among newspapers and news websites.
Why has the usage of "mass transit" seen such a sharp decline in recent years, at least where literature and non-fiction are concerned? I confess I cannot begin to guess.

The term mass transit is common in urban planning: 06 Dec 2022
Leeds City Council set to reaffirm its commitment to mass transit in West Yorkshire and: Milton Keynes City Council already has ambitious plans to boost MK’s smart city reputation through delivering a modern mass transit system. The study will analyse how the systems could be integrated and build on the City Council’s innovation and sustainability ambitions. https://www.milton-keynes.gov.uk/news/2023/major-boost-advanced-rapid-transport-mk for example

WIKIPEDIA
Public transport (also known as public transportation, public transit, mass transit, or simply transit) is a system of transport for passengers by group travel systems available for use by the general public unlike private transport, typically managed on a schedule, operated on established routes, and that may charge a posted fee for each trip.
There it is.
Public transport on Wikipedia
[Little note: Mass transit in Massachusetts means the public transportation in the Greater Boston and Boston area.]
I dislike citing Wikipedia like this but I wanted to refrain from answering in comments.
To come and go somewhere by mass transit or public transportation. Also, to take mass transit or public transportation

Many people have seen the benefits of going to work by mass transit aka mass transit.
BUT:
Many people take mass transit or public transportation to go to work.


Yes, I also saw the definition on Wiki and dictionaries and thought they were the same. But people commenting above thought otherwise. Is there perhaps a regional difference?

@AnIELTSLearner - there is a 'regional difference' - British people mostly don't call their public transport systems 'mass transit'.

@Michael Harvey Mass transit is an urban planning term. I doubt most of us would say anything other than: I came by car, train, bicycle, plane, donkey cart etc. That said, one could say mass transit to differentiate it for a particular reason. lawyer: Did you come by a private car service? Answer: No, I came by mass transit.

Or better, at a town council: How do most students come to school? Answer: Mass transit aka public transportation. In the US, we don't call it that either necessarily. We say public transportation versus UK public transport, but it does not merit a downvote.

I don't think you deserve it either. I think people should give a reason when they downvote an answer.

@AnIELTSLearner Thanks for your comment. I think other forces are at work. But hey, that's the stupid internet. :) What especially annoys me are dv's of the questions that don't deserve it. People seem to forget what a learner is and just judge from their own misguidedness.

@Lambie - for the sake of my sanity, I made a pact with myself to ignore downvotes.

@MichaelHarvey Did you see all the dv's I received on that question about food tasting good when you are very hungry? Minus 6!!  I guess Bible thumping and aphorisms are de rigueur, not actually answering questions. I mean who would do that? [sardonically]

In the US, public transportation is most often associated with buses and trolleys, which stop and start a lot in traffic,  and "mass transit" refers to the entire system of transportation in a metro area, which would include regional rail (suburban ridership going into the city and back out), bus lines, high-speed elevated, subways and trolleys.
Someone who commutes via regional rail to a job in a high-rise office building in the city might well say "I never take public transportation".
P.S. Specifically with regard to the use of preposition by...
The object of preposition by in this sense can be a specific type of  vehicle:

They went by {private car, train, subway, taxi, ...} into the city.

But we can also say "by mass transit" with the meaning "using one or more of the people-moving  modalities the metro area offers" (I.e. not in our own car or by taxi).

An integrated approach
The strategy has three components: mass transit, walking and cycling, and managing
traffic and travel demand. There is no single solution to tackle Oxford’s long-term
challenges: all three components are needed in combination to deliver the objectives of the
OTS. https://www.oxfordshire.gov.uk/sites/default/files/file/roads-and-transport-connecting-oxfordshire/ConnectingOxfordshireOxfordTransportStrategy.pdf

@Lambie I don't know what you're trying to say with that excerpt that uses the phrase "mass transit".  It seems to include everything other than bicycles and walking.  Are they including private vehicle traffic/roads systems under "mass transit"?

Everyone is assuming that the OP's sentences are not right on. They are in fact fine. Her sample sentences are great and in them public transportation, public transport (perhaps more British, not sure) or mass transit are fine. They are basically synonyms...I posted the British thing to show one of the options. In planning, urban planning, city planning etc. the terms are all standard.

@Lambie Then why are you specifically telling me this?  My final paragraph says we can use "by mass transit". Is it that you're including using one's personal vehicle  as a use of mass transit because the system of roads is part of mass transit, and I've distinguished between personal vehicles and taxis on the one hand, and people-moving modalities on the other?

My whole point is that all these terms are the same thing, as given in the Wikipedia article's first sentence.
